# How to perform a contour integral where the contour is two lines?

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

I have this straightforward problem where I don't understand the choice of the curves from my professor.

Evaluate $\int \bar{z}dz$ where the curve connecting the points $z_1=0$ and $z_2=1+i$ is made of the two lines:
$$\Gamma_1:x=0$$
$$\Gamma_2:y=i$$

I chose my curves for the integration in the following way: just plug in the given values of $x$ and $y$ from the conditions of the problem in $z=x+iy$ which gives me:
$$\gamma_1(t) = it, 0 \leq t \leq 1$$
$$\gamma_2(t) = t-1, 0 \leq t \leq 1$$

However the professor wrote:
$$\gamma_1(t) = it,0 \leq t \leq 1$$
$$\gamma_2(t) = t+i,0 \leq t \leq 1$$

I know that there is a formula for a straight line based on the points given but I can't find a way to get those contours right each time.

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get the parametrization of the line starting from the point $a+ib$ to the point $c+id$ here is how to make sense of the general formula and hopefully how to understand it.

You want your line to start at $a+ib$, at $t=0$, you want $\gamma(0) = a+ib$. At $t=1$, you want $\gamma(t) = c+id$. An easy way to do it is to take the formula
$$\forall t \in [0, 1], \ \gamma(t) = (1-t)(a+ib) + t(c+id) $$
You'll get that at $t=0$ the factor $t$ will be $0$ and $1-t$ will be $1$ and vice-versa at $t=1$. If you know a bit about convex functions this formula for a line appears in the inequality
$$ f((1-t)x + ty) \leq (1-t)f(x) + tf(y) $$
It means that the value of $f$ on the line from $x$ to $y$ in $\leq$ than the corresponding point on the line from $f(x)$ to $f(y)$. That's how I understood and learned the formula.
If you at least remember that the important factors are $t$ and $1-t$ you'll be able to check which one goes where by checking what you want your parametrization to be at $t=0$ and $t=1$. Checking the endpoints of your parametrization is the key idea to check if you got the right one, since a line is only determined by its endpoints.

Finally in your exemple, you get that
$$ \forall t \in [0, 1], \ \gamma_1(t) = (1-t)\cdot 0 + t\cdot i = it \quad \text{and} \quad \gamma_2(t) = (1-t)\cdot i + t \cdot (1+i) = t + i.$$
(note that $(1-t) z + t z$ is always equal to $z$).

Surely this is not the fastest method to get your parametrization but until you get familiar enough with the concept this might be one of the safest.

Comment: Another derivation of this formula uses vector arithmetic: given two points $P,Q$, the displacement vector from $P$ to $Q$ is $Q-P$, and the path from $P$ to $Q$ is then parameterized as $P + t(Q-P)$ ($0 \le t \le 1$), which simplifies to $(1-t)P+tQ$.

Comment: Thank you so much for this extensive explanation. Greatly appreciated, Merry Christmas !